# linking problem: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file *.o is incompatible with i386 output

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, linker, linker-scripts

I got a problem in linking when I moved my osdev to linux where it worked previously on gcc 3.5.* and binutils 2.18 (compiled to output x86_64-elf) running under cygwin.
Here are the infos:
**gcc -v**

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.4/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.4 --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.4 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.5 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5)
```

**ld -v**

```
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.20.51-system.20100908
```

part of **ld -help**

```
....

ld: supported targets: elf32-i386 a.out-i386-linux pei-i386 elf32-little elf32-big elf64-x86-64 pei-x86-64 elf64-l1om elf64-little elf64-big plugin srec symbolsrec verilog tekhex binary ihex trad-core

....
```

**The code:**

**main.c**

```
void main(){

    /**some code here**/

}
```

**start.asm**

```
[bits 64]

global start

extern main

start:

call main
```

**link.ld**

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64);

offset = 0x1000000;

ENTRY(start);

SECTIONS{

    . = offset;

    .text : AT(ADDR(.text) - offset){

        _code = .;

        *(.text)

        (.rodata)

        . = ALIGN(4096);}

   .data : AT(ADDR(.data) - offset){

        _data = .;

        *(.data)

        . = ALIGN(4096);}

   .bss : AT(ADDR(.bss) - offset){

       _bss = .;

       *(.bss)

       *(COMMON)

       . = ALIGN(4096);}

   _end = .;

   /DISCARD/ :

   {*(.comment)}

}
```

**build.sh**

```
nasm -f elf64 -o start.o start.asm

echo .

echo .

echo .

gcc -m64 -ffreestanding -nostdlib -mno-red-zone -mno-mmx -mno-sse -mno-sse2 -mno-sse3 -mno-3dnow -c -o main.o main.c

echo .

echo .

echo .

ld -nostdlib -nodefaultlibs -T link.ld -o out.elf start.o main.o
```

**terminal output**

```
.

.

.

.

.

.

ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file 'start.o' is incompatible with i386 output

ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file 'main.o' is incompatible with i386 output
```

I don't understand why it displays 'incompatible with i386 output' when there's OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64); in my linker script specifying the targeted output..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
LDEMULATION="elf_x86_64"
ld -nostdlib -nodefaultlibs -T link.ld -o out.elf start.o main.o
```

Comment: sorry, yes it did help.. I tried it as:
LDEMULATION="elf_x86_64" (with newline)
ld -nostdlib -nodefaultlibs -T link.ld -o out.elf start.o main.o


..thats why it didn't work at first..Btw, why do they made it like that? It made the 
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64);
useless...